# Right Click selection selects everything and not just 1 thing

Tags: selection-tools

I'm very new to blender and I just want it to make GFXs for a multiplayer website called ROBLOX. I've successfully made some about a month ago, but when I try to use right click to select a limb, Blender decides to select everything. This is an example of what is happening:
[image]

It's so annoying that I just want to stop making GFXs now.

Comment: It's selecting everything because it's one object.  You need to go to Edit Mode and separate the limbs if you want them to be separate... by pressing "P".

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But is there any way to always make it seperated?  That's how it was when I first downloaded Blender.

Comment: Yes, you can add the objects individually in Object Mode.  Blender allows you to add meshes to an existing object when in Edit Mode.  Just make sure you're in Object mode before you add meshes.  You can tell when you're adding in Object Mode because the icons are yellow, in Edit Mode, they're white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [bertmoog](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/38953/bertmoog) already said in his comment, the "human" in your scene is a single object, which you have selected.

To edit the vertices, edges and faces, you have to switch into edit mode bypressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or by using the menu in the bottom left corner.

If you want to seperate the single parts of your "human object", you have to enter edit mode, press <kbd>P</kbd> and select "By loose parts"